# Load album art into Glide using Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-glide

- Code to load album art

  ```
      if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){

          int titleColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
          int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
          int artistColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
          int albumColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
          long albumID = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID);

          do {
              long thisID = cursor.getLong(idColumn);

              String thisTitle = cursor.getString(titleColumn);
              String thisArtist = cursor.getString(artistColumn);
              String thisAlbum = cursor.getString(albumColumn);

              Glide.with(this)
                      .load(albumID)
                      .asBitmap()
                      .into() //How do I return a value?

              medialist.add(new SongInfo(thisID, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisAlbum, //Bitmap variable));
          }
          while (cursor.moveToNext());
  ```

I'm trying to load the album art into a listview using Glide. However, I'm having trouble in the;

> medialist.add(new SongInfo(..);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing wrong:
use this:

```
medialist.add(new SongInfo(thisID, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisAlbum,albumID));
```

Now, in your listview adapter class, get medialist and in glide method:
define:

```
Context con;
```

Now in Constructor of adapter:

```
public CustomAdapter(List<Medialist> items, Context context) {
        medialist= items;
        this.con = context;
    }

Glide.with(con)
                    .load(medialist.getAlbumID)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .into(imageview)
```

Comment: hi @Divyesh

I'm unable to initialize Glide.with(this) in my adapter class, it says unresolve method, what do I place in after Glide.with(..).